# Adding legend and colour each bar differently

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot the distribution of the classes.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv')
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc="count",  x=df['variety'], showlegend=True))
fig
```

---

This gives me:

[image]

I want the legend to be `Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica` 
and each bar with different colour.

Using pandas I can do (Although There is problem with legend there):

```
ax = df['variety'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
ax.legend(df.variety.unique())
```

[image]

I want this to be integrated with plotly dash so I am using plotly go. If someone can help me with this issue. It would be a great help to me as I am newbie in plotly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to add each trace individually for all the unique values of variety (or species in my data).  When adding each trace use the `name` argument so that the legend can be populated with the appropriate text.  So something like:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

var = df.species.unique()
fig = go.Figure()
for v in var:
    fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc="count",  
                               x=df.species[df.species==v], 
                               showlegend=True,
                               name=v
                              )
                 )

fig
```

[image]

Comment: How to integrate it with plotly dash ?

Comment: I think the [standard method](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#what-about-dash)